# Opening Internet Explorer 100% Hidden

Tags: vbscript

I have a ClickOnce application and I want to create an exe that autoruns the weblink using Internet Explorer. I would like it to run seamless and professionally such that no pop-ups etc. appear.

I have created a batch file that runs a VBS file, which launches Internet Explorer and runs the link, the Internet explorer window is hidden, but the icon for Internet explorer still appears on the task bar.

This is the code used to launch Internet Explorer:

```
Dim ie

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = False

ie.Navigate "https://google.com"
```

To give you an example of what I'm trying to achieve, the following application https://www.jitbit.com/bat-to-exe/

Manages to run a clickonce application seamlessly without any taskbar icons showing Internet explorer, but I can't seem to reverse engineer its method

Answer (score 0):

For anyone also wanting to open a ClickOnce weblink using a single exe

Create an application that runs the following CMD line:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>rundll32.exe dfshim.dll, ShOpenVerbApplication https://yourweblink

It is as simple as that.

This way, no browser is used at all.